# Safari's Voiceover only reads webpage title and summary, how to make it read the entire page?

Tags: accessibility

Macbook's voiceover is only reading the webpage title and page summary on Safari and stops. It's not reading the entire page from title to the end of the page. It works on Chrome, it reads the entire page automatically without key press. I still need to press <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to continue it reading. Is this normal in Safari?

> , has 1 link...

after reading the page title and summary it will say

> You are currently in a link...

And I will press <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to continue reading the remaining elements in the page.

Comment: See https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/voiceover/mchlp2719/10/mac/13.0